# What is this flag widget in the Pages ruler?

Tags: macos, pages

What is the flag-like widget to the right of the left margin marker (indicated with red arrow)? I know that this has something to do with indentation and tabs, but it doesn't seem to be a tab stop. Maybe something to do with a line leader? Hard to search for help with something when you're not even sure what to call it.

[image]